# In Azure Managed Service Identity - how frequently does the certificate renew

Tags: azure-managed-identity

If I understand correctly - Azure Managed Service Identity provisions the certificate to your service automatically and also handles its renewal.
The question is - what's the renewal frequency for that cert and can it be customized?

Answer (score 1):

Managed identities use certificate-based authentication. Each managed identity’s credential has an expiration of 90 days and it is **rolled after 45 days**. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/known-issues#what-is-the-credential-associated-with-a-managed-identity-how-long-is-it-valid-and-how-often-is-it-rotated))

It cannot be customized, as it is an internal implementation detail of managed identities.

Answer (score 0):

With a managed identity you no longer have to worry about generating, renewing or securing the credentials. All that is managed for you by the service, giving you a very simple interface to obtain tokens, and allowing you to focus on building your solution.

It really depends on your security requirements.

As a base I would say:one year renewal for certificate. Automatically renew it after 11 months. Set rollover time to 3 weeks.
If you are using long lived access tokens you might need to adjust this.

Comment: Thanks Joey, do you have a source for this info? Also what is the difference between the three intervals you supplied in your reply?